# How is the Petersen graph homeomorphic to a subdivision of bipartite $K_{3,3}$ graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone explain to me how these graphs are homeomorphic?

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: @Hagen he did say *homeomorphic* not *isomorphic*.  The question is related to "why is the peterson graph non-planar" which is because it has a $K_{3,3}$ as a topological minor.  Indeed, you can check, in the lower picture, each vertex is adjacent only to things that it is adjacent to in the upper graph (and in some cases adjacent to fewer things [which is perfectly acceptable]).

Comment: @JMoravitz So is the Petersen graph homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ or is it just a subgraph of the Petersen graph that is homeomorphic? I'm learning too! I can't find an isomorphic subdivision.

Comment: I'm looking up a concrete definition for homeomorphic.  It appears as though the widely used definition is "Two graphs are *homeomorphic* iff they can both be obtained as subdivisions of the same graph", in which case adding edges would not be allowed (only creation of vertices of degree two along an existing edge).  Under that definition, the graphs are not homeomorphic, but both have subgraphs (by deleting edges) that are homeomorphic to $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes sense. In that case, for OP: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~mwilliams/pdf/petersen.pdf

Comment: Thanks alot @JMoravitz. Your explanation helped me understand it. I wasn't sure how they could just put for example c as neighbour of b and d, and not with h.