# difference between Kuratowski's theorem and Wagner's theorem?

Tags: graph-theory

These theorems stated by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski's_and_Wagner's_theorems) seems very similar; difficult to decipher the difference. Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kuratowski's theorem is about subgraphs; Wagner's theorem is about minors. Every subgraph is a minor, but not vice versa: to get a minor you are allowed to merge vertices along a common edge, but to get a subgraph you are only allowed to delete edges (and vertices).

A good example of this is given by the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph):

[image: picture of Petersen graph]

It has $K_5$ as a minor: in the standard pentagram picture you can see above, you can contract the edges connecting the inner and outer vertices to get a $K_5$. However, it does not have any subdivision of $K_5$ as a subgraph (this would require that it have vertices of degree 4).

So you can combine one direction of Wagner's theorem and the other direction of Kuratowski's theorem to conclude that the Petersen graph must contain a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$, even though this is not immediately obvious. (If you're curious, you can see such a subdivision [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271659/how-is-the-petersen-graph-homeomorphic-to-a-subdivision-of-bipartite-k-3-3-g).)

Comment: By the way, the converse case does not exist: If a graph has $K_{3,3}$ as a minor, then necessarily it also contains a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph.

Comment: Kuratowski's theorem is about **subdivisions**, not subgraphs.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: In this context, I disagree. It is about subgraphs (of the graph in consideration) which are subdivisions (of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$). That is, it is about subgraphs in the sense that Wagner's theorem is about minors.

Comment: My point is that you can't replace "minor" with "subgraph" in the statement of Wagner's theorem and get Kuratowski's theorem.

Comment: No, but you can replace "subgraph" with "minor" in the statement of Kuratowski's theorem and get (something which is trivially equivalent to) Wagner's theorem...

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't if you want to avoid confusing people.

Comment: are both (forming minors and subgraphs) allowed to delete vertices? Specifically speaking, to get a minor, are vertex deletions allowed?

Comment: @B.Li: Yes, both are allowed to delete vertices. (But if the graph is connected, you don't need a separate vertex-deletion operation for minors; just delete all but one of the edges from that vertex, and then contract the remaining one...)